# How to access the pixels inside the convex hull?

Tags: python, image, opencv, contour, image-segmentation

Once we get the convexhull of an image, Is their any way to accsess the pixels which lie inside the convexhull.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import PIL

usg = cv2.imread("1.jpg",0)

ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(usg, 10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)            
hull = [cv2.convexHull(c) for c in contours]

final = cv2.drawContours(usg,hull,-1,(255,255,255))
```

Here, `final` gives the convex hull of the image. After that I want to access the pixels inside the hull.

Comment: Pls add the 1.jpg to question

Comment: for each  pixel you can test, whether it is in the polygon. If you draw the convex hull, you can use the image as a mask. By using subimages, you can reduce the full image to the relevant rectangle around the convex hull, which typically gives a nice speedup.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the drawn convex hull, you can simply use NumPy's [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to access the pixels within the convex hull.

Here's some examplary code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up dummy image
img = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.fillPoly(img, np.array([[[20, 20], [120, 40], [280, 30], [280, 350], [140, 320], [30, 380]]]), (0, 0, 255))

# Threshold image
_, img_thr = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find contours: OpenCV 4.x
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_thr, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Find contours: OpenCV 3.x
#_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_thr, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Convex hulls from contours in list
hulls = [cv2.convexHull(c) for c in contours]

# Draw convex hull of first contour
hull = np.zeros(img_thr.shape, np.uint8)
hull = cv2.drawContours(hull, np.array([np.squeeze(hulls[0])]), -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Access pixels inside convex hull; here add some green values to original image
idx = hull == 255
final = img.copy()
final[idx, :] = final[idx, :] + (0, 128, 0)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('hull', hull)
cv2.imshow('final', final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

That's the dummy image `img`:

[image]

That's the drawn convex hull `hull`:

[image: Convex hull]

That's the final image `final`, where the pixels within the convex hull in `img` have been modified:

[image: Final]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The convex hull is a convex polygon. You can enumerate the pixels inside the hull by implementing a polygon filling algorithm. In the case of a convex polygon, a scanline approach is easy.

- find a topmost vertex and note the two sides emanating from it;
- loop on the ordinates, downward;
- for every ordinate, ensure that the horizontal meets the left and right sides; if not, go to the next side(s) downward;
- join the left intersection to the right intersection; all the pixels on this segment are inside the hull;
- stop when the left and right sides meet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by first painting my convex hull white colour with cv2.fillPoly()  on a black frame

1. First create black frame that follows your frame's shape

   `black_frame = np.zeros_like(your_frame).astype(np.uint8)`
2. Paint the convex hull with white

   `cv2.fillPoly(black_frame , [hull], (255, 255, 255))`
3. Create a mask by using numpy boolean indexing, it will produce a mask with True/False values inside, it will be True is the pixel value is white

   `mask = black_frame == 255`
4. You can access your pixel values by getting the product between your frame and mask, if False, value will

   `targetROI = your_frame * mask`
5. Access your pixels by using the mask.

```py
black_frame = np.zeros_like(your_frame).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.fillPoly(black_frame , [hull], (255, 255, 255))
mask = black_frame == 255
targetROI = your_frame * mask
```